# Convert map value to another map object

Tags: java, hashmap, java-stream

I have a map like this. `Map<long,List<Student>> studentMap`

Key is a number 1,2,3,4...
Student object is :

```
public class Student {
 private long addressNo;
 private String code;
 private BigDecimal tax;
 private String name;
 private String city;

 // getter and setters` 
}
```

What i want to do is to convert it `Map<long,List<StudentInfo>> studentInfoMap` object and group id, addressNo and code fields.

I can group the map by using these codes but summingDouble is not working for BigDecimal.Also I cannot convert my studentMap to studentInfoMap.:(

```
 studentInfoMap.values().stream()
            .collect(
                     Collectors.groupingBy(StudentInfo::getCode, 
                     Collectors.groupingBy(StudentInfo::getAddressNo, 
                     Collectors.summingDouble(StudentInfo::getTax))));
```

My studentInfo object is :

```
public class StudentInfo {
  private long addressNo;
  private String code;
  private BigDecimal tax;

  // getter and setters` 
}
```

Comment: So you want to convert a `Map<Long,List<Student>>` to a `Map<Long,List<StudentInfo>>`? Are the keys the same?

Comment: Yes.Keys are same

Comment: Why are you doing this? This is totally unnecessary in my opinion. `Student` and `StudentInfo` are basically the same class. This is DEFINITELY a huge code smell.

Comment: Sorry.I updated my question

Comment: @tom No... even with the update, the contents of both classes are virtually the same. One of those classes  is not needed in the first place. So, there is no need to "convert" one instance for another. Since `StudentInfo` is a subset of `Student`, I would eliminate `StudentInfo`.

Comment: I want to group addressNo,code fields and to create a new map because it is new object.Tax is summing field

Comment: You can collect `Student` objects that meet that criteria. You don't need two virtually identical classes to do this.

Comment: You need to be somewhat more specific on what you actually want to group - ideally provide an example. Do you basically want to get a sum of tax values for each unique combination of `addressNo` and `code`?

Comment: Yeah.I want to group addressNo and code fields to get a sum of tax values but I  want my key will not be changed

Answer (score 6):

**Converting `Map<K, List<A>>` to `Map<K, List<B>>`**
If you want to convert a `Map<Long,List<Student>>` to a `Map<Long,List<StudentInfo>>` with the keys being the same, try the following:

```
Map<Long,List<StudentInfo>> convertedMap = 
  studentInfoMap.entrySet() //get the entry set to access keys and values
    .stream() 
    .collect(Collectors.toMap( //collect the entries into another map
        entry -> entry.getKey(), //use the keys as they are
        entry -> entry.getValue() //get the value list
                      .stream() /
                      .map(student -> new StudentInfo(/*pass in the student parameters you need*/) //create a StudentInfo out of a Student - and entry.getKey() if needed
                      .toList() //collect the StudentInfo elements into a list
     ));
```

**Reducing `List<A>` to `List<B>` by grouping A's based on key values**

***Create a key class***

If you want to collapse/reduce a `List<Student>` into a `List<StudentInfo>` by combining the taxes for each unique combination of `addressNo` and `code`, you'd ideally first define a class that combines those 2 attributes into a key, e.g.

```
class StudentAddressKey {
  private long addressNo;
  private String code;

  //getters, setters, equals() and hashCode()
}
```

You could then think about using this in `Student` instead of the individual keys but that's another topic.

***Traditional loop***

Then it comes down to summing tax values by this key. Using a traditional for-loop it could look like this:

```
Map<StudentAddressKey, BigDecimal> taxByKey = new HashMap<>();

for( Student student : studentList) {
  taxByKey.merge(student.getAddressKey(), //or build a new one from the individual attributes
                 student.getTax(), //the value to merge into the map
                 BigDecimal::add ); //called if there's already a value in the map, could also be (e,n) -> e.add(n)
}
```

If you want a `Map<StudentAddressKey, StudentInfo>` instead, you have 3 options:

- Create one for each `Student` you want to add, pass it to `merge()` and if there's already one combine the new and the existing one
- Use `get()` to get an `StudentInfo` already in the map if there is one. If you get `null` put a new one, otherwise just change the tax by adding the student's value
- Create the `Map<StudentAddressKey, BigDecimal>` and turn it into a `Map<StudentAddressKey, StudentInfo>` in the end, basically using the process I described above.

To get a `List<StudentInfo>` (which might not be necessary if you already have a `Map<StudentAddressKey, BigDecimal>`) you again have a couple of options:

- If you have a `Map<StudentAddressKey, BigDecimal>` then stream the entry set, map each entry to a `StudentInfo` and collect to a List.
- If you have a Map<StudentAddressKey, StudentInfo>`just create a new list and pass the map's`values()` to the list constructor

***Stream***

Using the info above, you can also use a stream to convert `List<Student>` to `List<StudentInfo>`:

```
Map<StudentAddressKey, BigDecimal> taxesMap = studentList.stream()
  .collect( 
     Collectors.groupingBy( student -> new StudentAddressKey(student), //create the key to group by
        Collectors.mapping( student -> student.getTax()), //map the student to its tax value
          Collectors.reducing( BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add) //reduce the mapped tax values by adding them, starting with 0 (otherwise you'd get an Optional<BigDecimal>
        )
      )
    );
```

Note: you could also directly map `Student` to `StudentInfo` but merging them would be more complex and since all you need is a single `BigDecimal` I'd go for the simpler option.

Now use the approaches above to convert `taxesMap` into a `List<StudentInfo>`:

```
List<StudentInto> taxesList = taxesMap.entrySet().stream()
                .map( entry -> new StudentInfo(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue)) //map the entry to StudentInfo, provide the necessary constructor or adapt as needed
                .toList();
```

Comment: Why would you encourage a bad design implementation? There is no need to convert one type for the other. One type is a subset of the other. At least advice him that this is a bad design decision. No need to complicate the code with unnecessary conversions when the code will be completely fine with just one class.

Comment: Thank you very much.Converting is succesfull.Grouping addressNo and code fields and summing tax is not working .Do you know summing function for BigDecimal

Comment: @hfontanez well, the OP using classes like `Student` indicates this is a learning excercise and while I agree that one class seems to be a subset of the other this might be a restriction or at least a design aspect that's not within the scope of the question. Also, tbh, there may be cases where you actually need to do something like this in production ready code.

Comment: @Thomas I have used Adapter pattern for similar cases, but even then, the data types of the members of the classes are different. This is clearly not the case. But, I digress...

Comment: Actualy.I wanted group addressNo and code by summing tax field.It creates new object so I  wanted to convert it to new object.

Comment: @tom I've added some more, check it out. I didn't provide a ready-to-copy solution but you should get enough info to combine everything as needed.

Comment: @Thomas what is the `student.getAddressKey()` in traditonal loop.

Comment: @tom that's refering to the section above, i.e. if you're building that key class I'd use it in `Student` as well. The alternative is mentioned in the comment for that line.